# How does data retrieval happen in KairosDb?

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb, kairos-api

I have data like below:-

```
data = [
{
    "name": "test4",
    "datapoints": [
        [currentTimestamp, count]
    ],
    "tags": {
        "name" : "MyName",
        "dept" : "Engineering",
        "city" : "Delhi",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "country" : "India"

    }
    }
]
```

And I am sending data to KairosDB server by using python script like this -

```
  response = requests.post("http://localhost:8080" + "/api/v1/datapoints", json.dumps(data))
```

I know this data will be stored in three different tables:-

```
1. string_index
2. row_keys
3. data_points
```

And my query is :-

```
{
"metrics": [
{
  "tags": {},
  "name": "test4",
  "aggregators": [
    {
      "name": "sum",
      "sampling": {
        "value": "1",
        "unit": "milliseconds"
      }
    }
  ]
}
],
"plugins": [],
"cache_time": 0,
"start_absolute": 1529346600000
}
```

Now I want to know that how data will get fetched from those three tables, I mean what will the flow of data retrieval from Cassandra.

Thanks In Advance.